# Superscript greater than three does not work. Only one two and three available

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm querying a database and trying to get superscripts. The first three work fine, others don't though. What are the valid superscript characters for anything over three?

1:   NCHAR(185)
2:NCHAR(178)
3:NCHAR(179)
 4: NCHAR(8308)
                                               5:NCHAR(8309)
                                              6:NCHAR(8310)
                                              7:NCHAR(8311)
                                              8:NCHAR(8312)
                                             9:NCHAR(8313)

Comment: I put Lucida Sans unicode font and it makes no difference. (on the reprot)

Answer (score 1):

Simply search the web for characters named SUERSCRIPT FOUR, etc.

You will find pages such as this, for superscript 4:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2074/index.htm

The characters you have seem to be at the correct decimal codepoints; perhaps the issue is with the fonts.  You'll just have to find fonts that support these characters.

Also check that the character encoding of your database is UTF-8 and not, say, Latin-1.

Comment: That's what I'm saying 8308 does not give me superscript four. It gives me plain number four

Comment: I mean the type of a column: NCHAR(200) in a create table statement would specify a column of type unicode text of length 200.  I take it, though that you are specifying actual strings?  Are you using NCHAR in these expressions?

Comment: I'm using this: SELECT NCHAR(185), NCHAR(186)..etc. I do not have a column. I manually select superscripts. Does this answer your question? I've tried to declare column, it says that length cannot be over 8000.

Comment: My mistake.  NCHAR is overloaded as both a column type and as a function which converts an integer to the character with that codepoint.  When you say SELECT NCHAR(8308) are you displaying the result in a terminal window or in a graphical client?  Terminal apps like CMD.EXE sometimes don't do higher-codepoint characters very well.

Comment: I do it in ssms and in reporting services 1-3 works. 4-9 does not

Comment: I cannot see to find utf collation definition, my collation is: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, but I don't think that this will make a difference if I change to utf.

Comment: @user194076: FWIW, the following displayed correctly in my SSMS (SQL Server 2008 R2): `SELECT N'x' + NCHAR(8308)` (the `x` letter, followed by the superscipt `4`).

Comment: @Andriy M: Does not show for me. Can you please tell what font and collation you're using?

Comment: @user194076: The effective collation was `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. I was able to view the result both in grid and in text, which means the fonts used were Tahoma and Liberation Mono, respectively. But the superscript character was apparently from a different font, and I think it was substituted by the OS, which is Windows 7.

Comment: I have windows 7 with Tahoma in grid and the same collation. hm, So it looks like some kinda of windows settings? Is there any way you can discover what is the fonttype of the superscript characters? Probably here? http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/. Or can you attach an image please?